# How to transfer DAG tokens from MetaMask wallet to KuCoin

Tags: metamask, constellation

Using my MetaMask wallet, I purchased some DAG tokens (Constellation) and now want to transfer them to KuCoin. However, the DAG wallet address inside the KuCoin seems to be incorrect because when I copy/paste the address into MetaMask it says "Recipient address is invalid". I have tried reaching to the Exchange support but they are not helpful. Has anyone had the same issue? any ideas if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Ask Constellation Community. It is a separate blockchain from Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

After some research found that the DAG tokens on ERC20 network are worthless. They were converted to Constellation networkearlier this year, but unfortunately you can still get the old ERC20 tokens which is useless. I guess crypto is unregulated and need to do your own research :/ I learnt it the hard way.